# Maintaining data in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Example**

1. I click on my extension
2. opens the html page of my extension (popup.html)

   [image]
3. I add an element that has the text, the text of the prompt

   [image]
4. "abandoned" the extension
5. Control the listbox and the new first element inserted is not in the listbox

   [image]

There is my

[popup.html](http://pastebin.com/X65V9n5w)

Comment: You're not using [`localStorage`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/local-storage/info) in thar extension. One question: Why do you include IE-specific code in a CHROME extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you opened a text file, wrote some text in it and didnt save it? What do you think would happen?

You need to save the state of the content somewhere and this can be done using localStorage.

Here is an article which explains all about it:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Answer (score 1):

Better than HTML5 localStorage, consider leveraging the [chrome.storage API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/storage.html)